# How to find php files with code outside of a function or class and doesn't contain a string?

Tags: php, grep

I want to find php files with code outside of a function - basically ignore library and class files.

Then check if those files call a function - its a security function called require_login()

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding files which have code outside of classes and function is non-trivial.

Instead:

- I am looking for any files which defining classes, interfaces or functions and excluding them and returning all non-matching files.
- Then looking for anything in that list which is a php file.
- Then looking for anything calling require_login.

`grep -rEL "^\ *(function|([Aa]bstract |[Ff]inal )?class|[Ii]nterface)" \
| grep ".php$" \
| xargs grep -L require_login`

Comment: Excellent, I just needed to add -L to find files that don't contain require_login - is it possible to exclude `*/lang/*` directories too?

Comment: Yes, the -L flag gets files without matches.

In order to exclude '/lang/' you can pipe it through grep -v as follows.


`grep -rEL "^\ *(function|([Aa]bstract |[Ff]inal )?class|[Ii]nterface)" 
| grep -v "/lang/" 
| grep ".php$" 
| xargs grep -L require_login`

Answer (score 0):

Sure, write a PHP parser, so you can easily figure out what's "outside" a function.

How would you handle something like this:

sillyprint.php:

```
<?php
    print($global);
```

main_library.php:

```
function foo() {
   $global = "Hello, world";
   include('sillyprint.php');
}
```

Would the "sillyprint" code be "outside" of a function? It's only ever executed when INSIDE a function...